# JSON-LD+Hydra link discovery

Tags: angularjs, rest, hateoas

I've been thinking about how to employ JSON-LD to drive an application according to the HATEOAS principle.

For example I could have a simple entrypoint object, which defines a link:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "users": { "@id": "http://example.com/onto#users", "@type": "@id" }
  },
  "@id": "http://example.com/api",
  "users": "http://example.com/users"
}
```

And the `#users` predicate would be defined as a `Link` using Hydra:

```
{
  "@context": "http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/context.jsonld",
  "@id": "http://example.com/onto#users",
  "@type": "Link"
}
```

All good so far: the application fetches the resource, then the `onto#users` resource would be dereferenced to discover the semantics.

The question is how should the implementer discover the URI of the `users` property from the JSON-LD document. Of course it is clearly defined in the `@context` in my example, but that URI could be declared as a QName:

```
"@context": {
  "onto": "http://example.com/onto#",
  "users": { "@id": "onto:users", "@type": "@id" }
}
```

or an external context could be used or multiple/nested contexts.

Is there a functionality in the Javacript JSON-LD library, which would return absolute URIs of any given property? Or is there a simple way to find it? A way which would work regardless of how the `@context` is structured? Something like

```
var jsonLd = /* some odc */
var usersUri = jsonLd.uriOf('users');
expect(usersUri).toBe('http://example.com/onto#users');
```

In other words I think I'm looking for a uniform API for reading the `@context`.

Comment: I'm doing it with `jsonld.expand`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265543/follow-all-links-in-json-ld-api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you can do what you're asking with the JavaScript JSON-LD (jsonld.js) library:

```
var jsonld = require('jsonld');

var data = {
  "@context": {
    "onto": "http://example.com/onto#",
    "users": {"@id": "onto:users", "@type": "@id"}
  },
  "users": "http://example.com/users"
};

jsonld.processContext(null, [null, data['@context']], function(err, ctx) {
  if(err) {
    console.log('error', err);
    return;
  }
  var value = jsonld.getContextValue(ctx, 'users', '@id');
  console.log('users', value);
});
```

However, it's questionable whether this is a good idea. It sounds like maybe you just want to use jsonld.expand(), which will turn all properties into full URLs. Or, you can use jsonld.compact() to transform any JSON-LD input using a context that is well known by your application.

Comment: Prove me wrong but I think compact isn't an option, because it requires the client to have up-front knowledge about the response contents.

Comment: Your client can't easily use JSON keys ("users") in the response without upfront knowledge either. If you don't have any upfront knowledge, you should be using fully-expanded URLs. That means using jsonld.expand(). If you have some kind of out-of-band knowledge about how the system works then you may be able to use jsonld.expand() and then construct your own deterministic context to produce some simplified JSON for your clients to use. (Most REST-based APIs could probably be mapped to simple JSON keys by just removing some base URI).

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to design a system where the server is dumb and the client is smart. Where the client tries to figure out the meaning of the keys the server is sending -- so it can reuse those same keys because the server won't be able to translate a URL to a key. I think most of these systems work much the opposite: the server can take a JSON-LD input that uses any context and can then recompact it using the context that it understands. The client can do whatever it wants -- using whatever context (or none at all) it wants to.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding how this tech would be used. It may help if you explained a bit more how this smart client would work and how someone would program an application using it.

Comment: The server should definitely accept any re-contexted JSON-LD  document. As long as the data is equivalent. My question is entirely about the client though I realize the approach would be fragile, because when the server changes it's context for any reason, the client would break.

Comment: What I expect is merely that the client should only know the API entrypoint and the follow the links. What I'm struggling with though in my case of AngularJS is mixing a generic data client with Angular's routing. And so given the example data above there would be a user controller with a /#users route. Given that I'm not really creating a generic client but still just a didicated client to my own data API, I doubt there is any big profit from developing a completely smart client

Comment: There's a presumption that using context makes it simpler to write concise, consistent code that doesn't have to be changed just because another application that shares the data uses a different context. It seems to me that you'd want the client to use a well-known context (or deterministically generated), otherwise any client-side code will have to change to accommodate changes to the server's context. When writing your own client it's reasonable to keep it in sync with your own server context, but trying to automate that just seems like yet another abstraction layer to keep track of, IMO.