# Follow all links in JSON-LD API

Tags: hateoas, json-ld

Say I want to consume an API that returns JSON-LD and follow all the links. (I'm experimenting with the [Hydra API-Demo](http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/api-demo/), but it should work with all JSON-LD APIs, not only [Hydra](http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra)-based ones. Any good APIs out there that I should try?)

So I want to follow all the links and my environment doesn't have native RDF support. Probably, I should first parse it with one of the libs and get it into [extended form](http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#expanded-document-form) with `jsonld.expand()`. Then I just grab all the values with key `@id`. Is that the recommended way to do it or am I missing some edge-cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the expansion API is to produce regular, context-free output (expanded form) for algorithmic processing -- which is exactly what it sounds like you want to do. So, yes, you've got the right approach; you shouldn't be missing any edge cases as I've understood you. After you have JSON-LD in expanded form, you can easily follow the @ids (and, if you also need to do some kind of analysis of the vocabulary/ontology, you can follow the properties which will then be fully-expanded URLs).

Comment: Thanks! Can you point me to one or two good JSON-LD APIs that I can use for testing?

Comment: There's some data here you can crawl (see the JSON-LD link at the bottom): http://dbpedia.org/page/Nissan_Motor_Indonesia, also here: https://dev.payswarm.com/i/manu (request application/ld+json).